# Strange behavior of a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

This function must count the number of nodes in a binary tree. Tree contains more than 1000 nodes, and the number of recursive calls supposedly to be the same, but the value of the variable 'count' is not greater than 10. Why? What i am doing wrong?

```
int tree_depth(BST_T *tree) {
    static int count;
    count++;
    if(tree->left!=NULL) tree_depth(tree->left);
    else if(tree->right!=NULL) tree_depth(tree->right);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `count` is not initialized. Do `static int count=0;`

Comment: Your `else` means that only one of the two sides can be checked, not both. Remove it.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix `static` variables are always initialized to zero.

Comment: Always? Is that documented behaviour?

Comment: I'm with @memo1288, you need to remove the `else`.

Comment: You realize, of course, that a pathological tree (one with all left links and no rights links, or vice versa) could cause a recursion depth that's the size of the whole tree (1000 nested calls), right?

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: Yes it is. C-Standard 6.7.8/10

Comment: thanks, removing `else` statement helped

Comment: yes, for non-balanced trees it is quit possible. @DavidRTribble

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix, Kevin - the bigger problem is that, even if `count` is initialized, because it's `static`, it will never be re-initialized when you count the nodes in a second tree... It really shouldn't be `static` at all, but that just makes it all the more important to initialized it explicitly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the comments, your main problem is the `else`. Getting rid of it will allow the code to count *both* branches of every subtree.

Another problem is that it's generally considered bad practice to use a static variable for things like this. Why not just have each call return the count of nodes in the subtree it is passed? That way your code is thread-safe, more correct, and just plain simpler:

```
int tree_depth(const BST_T *tree)
{
    int  count = 1;

    if (tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (tree->left != NULL)
        count += tree_depth(tree->left);
    if (tree->right != NULL)
        count += tree_depth(tree->right);
    return count;
}
```

I've also added a `const` to the tree, since you're not modifying the tree in any way, only reading it.

Also be aware that a pathological tree (i.e., one with all null left links or all null right links, which is essentially just a linked list instead of a tree tree), will cause *N* nested calls for a tree having *N* nodes.

**Addendum**

Made some corrections to the code above, per some of comments below. I also added an additional check to test whether the tree pointer itself is null.

Also, as @twalberg pointed out, using a static counter will fail on all calls after the first, since it's not re-initialized to zero on each call. Getting rid of it entirely makes the whole thing simpler, and thread-safe as well.

Comment: You probably want `int count = 1` there, otherwise the current node does not get counted... (Alternatively, `return count + 1;`...)

Comment: @David R Tribble, I'd make it as `const BST_T* const tree`, I usually also place `if's` body with braces, you got also missing bracket in the 2nd if ;)

Comment: I made some of the recommended improvements. I left the pointer itself as non-const, since this is usually not necessary. I also prefer *not* to use braces around single statements, especially in online forums where brevity makes for easier-to-read code. I did add an additional test of the tree pointer itself, though.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: Thanks, I had not counted on such a deep analysis of the code, I'm new to C, so i will consider your recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
int tree_depth(const BST_T *tree)
{ if (!tree)
    return 1 + tree_depth(tree -> left) + tree_depth(tree -> left);
  return 0;
}
```

Except, note that `tree_depth` is probably a confusing name for this function, as it's more like `count_nodes`...

Comment: Thanks, i missed that. This function originally was for another purpose, but I forgot to rename it

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do something with the return values, otherwise you only receive the first level's count. Try this:

```
if(tree->left!=NULL) 
  count += tree_depth(tree->left);
else if(tree->right!=NULL) 
  count += tree_depth(tree->right);
```

Comment: The idea itself is correct, but reduntant "else" should also be removed, as suggested in comments.

Comment: If `count` is static then this will massively over-count the answer.

Comment: That's true, I missed that declaration.